# How to upload images to a SQL database in Azure?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, openrowset

I've seen some queries to upload the images from a file, but I get this error message:

> Cannot bulk load because the file could not be opened

I went to the properties>security option of the file to give access to SQL, but I couldn't find the option to give the permission. Considering this is Azure from Microsoft, how do I give the access to my files so I can execute the query? I'm using `OPENROWSET` and this is my code.

```
INSERT INTO FOTOS_EMPLEADOS
values (1,'HOLA', (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as T1))
```

If there is a mistake with the code or other way to do it, please let me know.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL Database doesn't support load file from on-premise computer.

Please reference [OPENROWSET (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax):
[image]

If you want to do this, you need upload the images to Blob Storage:

Please see [Importing into a table from a file stored on Azure Blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#j-importing-into-a-table-from-a-file-stored-on-azure-blob-storage):

```
--> Optional - a MASTER KEY is not required if a DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL is not required because the blob is configured for public (anonymous) access!
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'YourStrongPassword1';
GO
--> Optional - a DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL is not required because the blob is configured for public (anonymous) access!
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
 WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
 SECRET = '******srt=sco&sp=rwac&se=2017-02-01T00:55:34Z&st=2016-12-29T16:55:34Z***************';

 -- NOTE: Make sure that you don't have a leading ? in SAS token, and
 -- that you have at least read permission on the object that should be loaded srt=o&sp=r, and
 -- that expiration period is valid (all dates are in UTC time)

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
          LOCATION = 'https://****************.blob.core.windows.net/curriculum'
          , CREDENTIAL= MyAzureBlobStorageCredential --> CREDENTIAL is not required if a blob is configured for public (anonymous) access!
);

INSERT INTO achievements with (TABLOCK) (id, description)
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK  'csv/achievements.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
   FORMAT ='CSV',
   FORMATFILE='csv/achievements-c.xml',
   FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage'
    ) AS DataFile;
```

Hope this helps.